# Sum of binomial coefficients multiplied by terms of arithmetic series

Tags: binomial-coefficients, arithmetic-progressions

I am trying to evaluate the sum of binomial coefficients multiplied by the terms of an arithmetic series. In my particular case, I am hoping to evaluate

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{2n}(6n - 3i){3n\choose i}.$$

Is a closed form expression for this sum available?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; would that allow me to evaluate the sum?

Comment: If we allow $i$ to run from $0$ to $3n$ of course there is a closed form. As stated I would not bet on the existence of a simple closed form, but good bounds for moderately large values of $n$ can be derived from the central limit theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following from the suggestion above, we can rewrite:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2m}(6m-3k)\cdot {}_{3m} \mathrm{C}_k$$
Factoring and separating,
$$3\left(\sum_{k=0}^{2m}2m\cdot {}_{3m} \mathrm{C}_k - \sum_{k=0}^{2m}k\cdot {}_{3m} \mathrm{C}_k\right)$$
Focusing on the first sum,
$$2m\sum_{k=0}^{2m} {}_{3m} \mathrm{C}_k$$
$$= 2m\frac{(3m)!}{(2m)!}\sum_{k=0}^{2m} {}_{2m} \mathrm{C}_k$$
And using the important identity
$$\sum_{k=0}^{N} {}_N \mathrm{C}_k=2^N$$
$$2m\frac{(3m)!}{(2m)!}\sum_{k=0}^{2m} {}_{2m} \mathrm{C}_k=\frac{(3m)!}{(2m-1)!} 2^{2m}$$
Now onto the other sum.
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2m}k\cdot {}_{3m} \mathrm{C}_k=\frac{(3m)!}{(2m)!}\sum_{k=0}^{2m}k\cdot {}_{2m} \mathrm{C}_k$$
Using the results found [from this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1847183/prove-sum-k-0n-k-binomnk-n-cdot-2n-1-using-the-binomial-th) we can evaluate this to be
$$\frac{(3m)!}{(2m)!}2^{2m-1}\cdot 2m= \frac{(3m)!}{(2m-1)!}2^{2m-1}$$
Thus,
$$3\left(\sum_{k=0}^{2m}2m\cdot {}_{3m} \mathrm{C}_k - \sum_{k=0}^{2m}k\cdot {}_{3m} \mathrm{C}_k\right)$$
$$=3\left(\frac{(3m)!}{(2m-1)!} 2^{2m} - \frac{(3m)!}{(2m-1)!}2^{2m-1}\right)$$
$$=\frac{3(3m)!}{(2m-1)!}2^{2m-1}$$
Now using $n=3m$ (which was edited out by OP),
$$=\frac{2n}{3} \frac{3\cdot n!}{(\frac{2n}{3}-1)!}2^{\frac{2n}{3}-1}$$
$$=n \frac{n!}{(\frac{2n}{3}-1)!}2^{\frac{2n}{3}}.$$

Comment: It appears OP has edited his question to replace $n$ with $3n$. So now my answer involving the $m$'s is now correct.

Comment: Note that  in general $\sum_{k=0}^{2m}\binom{3m}{k}\ne \frac{(2m)!}{3m)!}\sum_{k=0}^{2m}\binom{2m}{k}$. Take e.g. $m=1$.